# Is there a way to get the json content of files fetched through a CAML query?

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, file, json, pnp

```
const query =  `<Where>
    <Eq><FieldRef Name="File_x0020_Type"/>      
        <Value Type="Text">json</Value> 
    </Eq> 
</Where>`;
const xml = '<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query>' + query + '</Query></View>';  
const result = sp.web.lists.getByTitle('myassets').getItemsByCAMLQuery({'ViewXml':xml}).then((res:any).then((res:any) => { return res; })
```

Used the CAML query above to fetch files, but I can't get the json content of the files. I looked at the json returned and I don't see anything relating to the content of the files. Is there a way to get the content of several files fetched through CAML? I know there's a PnP method to fetch an individual json, but I need to get the json of every file fetched at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample demo:

```
const query =  `<Where>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name="File_x0020_Type"/>      
            <Value Type="Text">json</Value> 
        </Eq> 
    </Where>`;
    const xml = '<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query>' + query + '</Query></View>';  
    sp.web.lists.getByTitle('MyDoc2').getItemsByCAMLQuery({'ViewXml':xml},'FileRef').then((items:any) => {
      items.map((item)=>{
        console.log(item);
        sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(item.FileRef).getJSON().then((data)=>{
          console.log(data);
        })
      }) 
    })
```

[image]